# SQL scheduled jobs Failed Notification

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need idea or a way to check if my schedule jobs work and insert the right data. I Have a function that call a stored procedure to count inserted data from today and insert into specific field.

like this

```
SET @male = (select count(idUser) from (select idUser from #tmpLog2 where sex = 1 AND CAST(catchTime as date) = @DATE group by idUser)u);
SET @female = (select count(idUser) from (select idUser from #tmpLog2 where sex = 0 AND CAST(catchTime as date) = @DATE group by idUser)u);

INSERT INTO CatchLog
(
    [male],
    [female]
)
VALUES
(
    @male,
    @female
)
```

the stored procedure works OK, but sometime when today have a lot of data, the result inserted 0 for male / female.
It's possible to have 0 data inserted when today data really no male / female.

but sometime it inserted 0 but there are male n female data. Anyone can help me to check, how to check if the data inserted true and give some report or insert into error Log if data inserted not true?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is Your '@DATE' variable type of date?

Comment: yes, it help to filter todays data

Comment: Please add table definition, and sample data! How calculated table #tmpLog2? Can it be, that there is missing data while interted into #tmpLog2?

Comment: #tmpLog2 just a some log table, just name, time log, male/female.. tmpLog inserted perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what column are you using into Count() Function. But if you are using Nullable column into it then it may gives 0 even if record were added as column value is null.

Consider to use Primary key column or not Nullable column in count() argument.

Comment: that's the point, i need total male and female that logging for today, there is another way not using count?

Comment: you can add "Not Null "constraint to column. If its not hamper your db structure than i would suggest to go for it by setting it NOT NULL. By this way you dont need any other workaround for this.